# UIView Animation Options Repeat count

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I'm having some issue with my Swift code, I'm trying to make an UIImageView object fade away and reappear once, but having some issues with having the animation to play only once.

```
@IBOutlet weak var ball: UIImageView!

@IBAction func onFadeClick(_ sender: Any) {
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
      self.ball.alpha = 0.0
      }, completion: nil)
}
```

I have attempted to read the documentation and previous questions but all have mentioned to use setAnimationRepeatCount, but xcode has an error stating that it is depreciated in iOS13 (which also does not work). Is there any built in functions I could use to stop the animation after it playing once? I have read somewhere saying using a callback function and reinitialize the animation but I am not exactly sure how to do that. Or is it a better idea to use UIViewPropertyAnimator instead of UIView.animate?

I'm just starting to learn Swift, any help or guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following to achieve your goal :

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
         self.ball.alpha = 0.0
    }
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
         self.ball.alpha = 1
    }
}) { (isFinished) in

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works exactly as intended. However, I do not really understand some parts of it. I get the idea of using keyframes, but what does relativeDuration mean? The time taken for the keyframe? If so, should the sum of relativeDuration of all keyframes be equal to withDuration? And what does (isFinished) in mean? Sorry it seems like a bunch of questions!

Comment: In the exemple, the animation duration is set to `2` seconds. So relativeDuration is a fraction of this time. In the exemple, 0.5 will mean 0.5 * 2s = 1s. Same for relativeStart. If you change the overall animation duration to 20s, you don't have to edit every subanimation

Answer (score 4):

### Swift 5.x

The current iOS syntax replacement for deprecated approach could be writed like the example below:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration:1, 
               delay: 0.5, 
               options: [.curveEaseInOut, .autoreverse, .repeat]) {
     UIView.modifyAnimations(withRepeatCount: 3, autoreverses: true) {
        print("repeated stuff")
     }
} completion: { _ in
     print("done")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The iOS 13 replacement for the deprecated approach is https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/3043564-modifyanimations. Example:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration:1, animations: {
    UIView.modifyAnimations(withRepeatCount: 3, autoreverses: true, animations: {
       // whatever
    })
})
```

However, the deprecated approach does still work; it is just deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, however the ball disappears after the animation is done, I'd need the ball to have the alpha back to 1. I have tried setting alpha = 1 in parts of the animate function call but it does not seem to do what I want, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

instead of the last }) use:

```
}, completion: { finished in
    self.alpha = 1
})
```