# UIView.animate with limited repeat and autoreverse glitches on a real device

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, ios16, scaletransform

I'm trying to make a simple scale animation of a button `1.0` -> `1.4`, repeat 3 times and then stop, but I'm experiencing a glitch on a real device.

The code below works **smoothly on a simulator**, but on a real device (iPhone 12 Pro with iOS 16) it glitches and I can see the jump to scale `1.4` after animation is done, and then it jumps to scale `1.0` on completion where I set `transform = .identity`.

I've suspected `UIView.modifyAnimations`, but the same problem happens with the now deprecated `UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(3)`.

Here is the video of the glitch on the real device:
https://i.imgur.com/x1LJ9Ox.mp4

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, animations: {
    UIView.modifyAnimations(withRepeatCount: 3, autoreverses: true) {
        self.titleButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.4, 1.4)
    // self.titleButton.layoutIfNeeded()  // doesn't change anything
    }
}, completion: { _ in
    self.titleButton.transform = .identity
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested on my iphone 13 iOS 16, it glitches like you said above.

Maybe I'm wrong or misunderstand something but looks like something is changing in `modifyAnimations(withRepeatCount:autoreverses:animations:)`.

In simulator, after the animation in `modifyAnimations` is done, it  immediately go to `completion`. If in `completion` do nothing with the view, it will turn back to `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.4, 1.4)`. But if the view has `transform` anything, it will turn to that `transform`.

But in real device, after the animation in `modifyAnimations` is done, the view will immediately turn back to the final of animation which here is `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.4, 1.4)` ( the simulator doesn't have this step) then after that go to `completion`. This cause the glitches like you said.

I have a workaround for this situation

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    // stop at the half of the final repeat means no autoreverses accur at the end
    UIView.modifyAnimations(withRepeatCount: 2.5, autoreverses: true) {
        self.secondView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.4, 1.4)
     }
}, completion: { _ in
    // make final scale back here
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.secondView.transform = .identity
    })
})
```

Comment: This is a very interesting solution, and it works. You make 2.5 repetitions and then then the last 0.5 in the completion. The fact `withRepeatCount` is a `CGFloat` might be intentional for these kind of cases. Otherwise, why on earth would they not make it a simple `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like iOS 16 is updating the transform 1 event loop after the animation resulting in the glitch.  One way to work around this is to leave the scale at 1.0 at the end of the animation itself by using a keyframe animation (which I found at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60152901/1630618)) and adding the code to repeat 3 times:

```
   UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
        UIView.modifyAnimations(withRepeatCount: 3, autoreverses: false) {
            
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
                self.titleButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.4, 1.4)
            }
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
                self.titleButton.transform = .identity
            }
        }
    }) { (isFinished) in

    }
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. But @bewithyou answer seems to be more straight forward use of `UIView.modifyAnimations`